# Is it possible to assign 1 domain to 2 different ip address (internet & intranet user)?

Tags: dns

Currently I have a domain (example : www.danra.com) and a server with 2 ip (10.x.x.x ->> private ip and 202.x.x.x ->> public ip)

And I want to differentiate DNS route according to where the users access my site (intranet or internet).
As example for intranet user, when users access www.danra.com, will be routed to ip 10.x.x.x, but when public users access it, will be routed to ip 202.x.x.x

Can I set my domain to those 2 ip on my server ?

Comment: Yes, in the intranet, you should setup an internal DNS that point to private IP. External use public DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. But it means you have to administrate a DNS server in your intranet.
Please refer to this : [How do I setup DNS for intranet](https://serverfault.com/questions/518079/how-do-i-set-up-dns-for-an-intranet-web-site). Route your intranet request to point to private IP. This means any request to www.danra.com will not go outside your intranet, use your local DNS Server and route it to your private IP.

Meanwhile, request from external users should point to public ip, this is achievable by buying a domain and point your domain to your public IP.
Here is an example using [Namecheap](https://help.shopify.com/manual/domains/connecting-existing-domains/common-providers/namecheap).

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rudy
yeah I try to call the network administrator in my office to set up DNS server in my intranet, so my expected route could be done